Substitute Expand operator with some other operator in ONNX
I have  an expand operator in the middle if a model that takes 2 inputs with the following shapes:
Output from sigmoid: 1,256,1,1 (tensor to be expanded)
Shape operator: 1,256,80,80 (output shape expected)
I can't use Expand, Tile, Constant and Slice operator due to some external issues. I need to substitute this expand operator to some other operator(s) to get the equivalent functionality.
I tried to substitute them with Reshape + Concat as these are well supported for my hardware but I can't exactly figure out how I can modify the model structure using Onnx.helper.
I wanted to reshape it first to 1,256 and then concat along last dimension 80 times to get 1,256,80 and then again in second last dimension for 1,256,80,80
But I don't understand how to modify the node. If the node is like:
``Input: "701"

input: "900"

output: "703"

axis: -1

name: "custom_added_Concat1"

op_type: "Concat"

I tried changing input 900 to ["701"] * 80 but it didn't work and as I can't create a constant node, I don't want to add 80 concat nodes for a single dimension.
I am very new to Onnx and protobuf and I tried all this from the documentation available but I couldn't find any reference to this.
